# How to make a fast functional mergesort and generators

Tags: python, functional-programming, generator, mergesort

Hi I am trying to make a merge sort algorithm in python. I want to do it as functional as possible and avoid loops and assignments as much as possible. Right now my function is not fast enough.

Someone told me that I have to change my split function because that is the one which is slowing me down, because it has a running time of O(n)

I can not imagine right now how I can change it. I think I should get rid of all the lists in favor of iterators/generators. But as I see it right now I have to change my design fundamentally if I should yield from the split function.

Also, I was wondering if all my if else statements is coursing too much computer thinking?

And also, is it possible that I could improve the code with currying?

```py
def split(xs, half):
    return (xs[:half], xs[half:])

def msort(xs):
    length = len(xs)
    if length <= 1:
        yield from xs
    else:
        yield from merge(*(msort(x) for x in split(xs, length//2)))

def merge(xs, ys, x=None, y=None):
    if not y:
        y = get(ys)
    if not x:
        x = get(xs)
    if x and y:
        if x <= y:
            yield x
            yield from merge(xs, ys, y=y)
        else:
            yield y
            yield from merge(xs, ys, x=x)
    else:
        if x:
            yield x
            yield from xs
        if y:
            yield y
            yield from ys

def get(xs):
    try:
        return next(xs)
    except StopIteration:
        return None
```

Comment: How long does it take and how much should it be faster by expectation?

Comment: Fully functional programming is not appropriate for some algorithms. In this case, the issue is iteration and modification of an array is replaced with making | returning copies and recursing for every element merged, which will be inherently slow, and overflow the stack on large arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your split function is indeed a bottleneck here as it creates sublists with all the memory overhead that it represents.  If msort() was designed to process an iterator, then you could change split() to return two iterators (e.g. one for odd positions and one for even positions).  This would eliminate most of the memory allocation and management in the sort process.

Here's an example of what I have in mind:

```
from itertools import tee,islice
def split(xs,size):
    i1,i2 = tee(xs)                   # two iterators
    s1,s2 = size//2 + size%2, size//2 # corresponding sizes (evens, odds)
    yield islice(i1,0,None,2),s1      # even positions (iterator,size)
    yield islice(i2,1,None,2),s2      # odd positions  (iterator,size)

def msort(xs,size=None):                       # use iterators when recursing
    if size is None:size = len(xs)             # first call expects a list
    if size == 1: yield from xs; return        # don't split single item
    yield from merge(*(msort(i,s)                   # msort(iterator)
                       for i,s in split(xs,size)))  # split as iterators

def merge(xs, ys, x=None, y=None):
    if not y:
        y = next(ys,None)   # using next(..,default) instead of try/except
    if not x:
        x = next(xs,None)
    if x and y:
        if x <= y:
            yield x
            yield from merge(xs, ys, y=y)
        else:
            yield y
            yield from merge(xs, ys, x=x)
    else:
        if x:
            yield x
            yield from xs
        if y:
            yield y
            yield from ys
```

output:

```
print(*msort([2,3,5,6,3,2,3,4])) # 2 2 3 3 3 4 5 6
print(*msort([4,6,5,1,7,2,3]))   # 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
print(*msort([5,6,4,1,2,3]))     # 1 2 3 4 5 6
print(*msort([5,4,3,2,1]))       # 1 2 3 4 5
print(*msort([21,32,17,23]))     # 17 21 23 32
print(*msort([17, 3,10]))        # 3 10 17
print(*msort([5, 3]))            # 3 5
print(*msort([1]))               # 1
```

*Note that this still has lots of room for improvements, it's just an illustration of the iterator approach.*

If you streamline the even/odd strategy into the algorithm, the split() function could be eliminated in favour of a slicing approach directly in msort():

```
from itertools import islice
def mySort(A,start=None,step=None):
    if start is None: start,step = 0,1
    eStart, eStep = start     ,step*2
    oStart, oStep = start+step,step*2
    if eStart >= len(A):
        yield from islice(A,oStart,None,oStep)
    elif oStart >=len(A):
        yield from islice(A,eStart,None,eStep)
    else:
        yield from merge(mySort(A,eStart,eStep),mySort(A,oStart,oStep))
    
def merge(A,B,a=None,b=None):
    if a is None: a = next(A,None)
    if b is None: b = next(B,None)
    if   a is None: yield b; yield from B
    elif b is None: yield a; yield from A
    elif a<b:       yield a; yield from merge(A,B,b=b)
    else:           yield b; yield from merge(A,B,a=a)
```

Note that, in both cases, the recursion depth will be 2*len(A) so you won't be able to sort arrays larger than about 490 elements.

Comment: Thank you. I didnt know that you can do that with the next function, that was very helpful

Comment: if I am trying to sort a list of an uneven amoint then something goes wrong with this soulution

Comment: if I give it the list `[17, 3, 10]` I will get `[3, 17, 10]`

Comment: Made changes to take odd/even sizes into account in the split() function and communicate the appropriate size to msort()